# floating divs: align: middle

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at http://snowclub.gr/test_forum2/index.php?app=ccs&module=pages&section=pages&folder=&id=19, I'm trying to find a way to center every raw of those divs (floating left & containing the webcam live feed). The webcam divs are of the same size & not the same number of divs appear for different display size (naturally). But I want to have every raw of cam divs centered, no matter how divs in a raw (depending on screen size).
I also want the css solution to be valid for these:(IE7 and above, Chrome, Firefox, Safari).
Thank you!

Comment: I've tested it by adding "padding: 0 0 0 4%" in  #webcams #webcams_wrapper element and it worked, it were centered but can't test it in ie7. So you may try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove `float: left;` on your webcam wrapper divs it seems to work as you are describing. However, in IE7, it doesn't work. This might be because you're using inline-block, which in order to work in IE7 needs the following added to #webcams .webcam

```
zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
```

That may solve your issue. If not, at least IE7 will now render display-block properly.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, a:

```
.centered {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

should work. However, your HTML has a `width: 100%`. I've tried several variants and the only one which yielded some results (if you want to keep ".left" class) implies that in the `.webcam` class to add `margin-right:auto`.

If you remove the .left class in the webcam, it should work (it does "on the fly" on my chrome instance).

Answer (score 0):

Place all the divs into a wrapper and center the wrapper with `margin:0 auto;` set the width of the others margin's padding's etc and float them. Or set the wrapper to `position:relative;` then absolutely position the three divs